# Hook below product thumbnail

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to insert product video below the product thumbnail on Single Product Page and to be used as a rollover image. I'm unable to get the right hook for that position. I've tried `woocommerce_product_thumbnail`, `woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html`, `wp_get_attachment_image_src` but they aren't right.

Here is the snippet

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnail', 'action_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 20 );
function action_template_loop_product_thumbnail() {
    global $product;
   $file = get_field('product_video', $product->get_id());
    // print_r( $file );
    if( isset($file['url']) && ! empty($file['url']) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
        echo '<div><video width="98%" muted loop autoplay src="' . $file['url'] . '"></video></div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
add_action ('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'stek_after_image', 99);

function stek_after_image() {
    var_dump(123);
}
```